# mysql create a composite key with different data types

Tags: mysql, composite-key

So let's say I am trying to create a table in MYSQL that contains 3 columns, Id, Name and Price. How would I go about creating a composite key between the Id and Name, given that they are different data types? I have tried the following query but am presented with an error.

```
CREATE TABLE name_price (
id int NOT NULL,
name Varchar NOT NULL,
price int,
PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
```

);

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
    price int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
)' at line 3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Why not use `id` as your primary key?

Comment: I like composite keys, but in this example shouldn't the key be `name` + `price`? The table name suggests this. You can keep the `id` and make this a key too or get rid of it altogether.

Comment: That's a good point. So does keeping the ID free give you more flexibility when inserting data?

Comment: But in this case the id and name are two primary keys and I thought should you have a table that contains two primary keys you should make a new ID or make a composite key out of the two?

Comment: You can usually say what makes a record in a table unique. For a country this may be the ISO country code. For an employee this may be the employee number. Sometimes this is not one column alone. If your database contains multiple companies, an employee is no longer identified by their employee number alone, but by their employee number in combination with their company (because two different companies may have an employee 1234, but those are two different persons). This is a composite key.

Comment: You'd choose keys that don't change. So don't use the company name to identify a company, because it may change (e.g. 'Jones' => 'Jones And Sons') and you'd have to change this in the company table and all tables referring to this record. Sometimes you don't find such key and you make one up (e.g. you just call this company #1). Then you have created an ID and make this the primary key. Anyway, you still want the natural key to remain unique (i.e. no two companies that are both called 'Jones'). This is not a composite key; these are two different keys (company_id and company_name).

Comment: Some people use technical IDs in all their tables. So you may have a country table with the ISO country code *and* a country_id. You'd have two keys then (i.e. non-nullable unique columns), and you make one of these (usually the ID) the primary key.

Comment: In your case you have an ID, which should be unique in the table (otherwise it shouldn't be called ID). You can make this the primary key. You also have a name and a price in this table. You call the table name_price. So it looks like you want to combine names and prices, e.g. 'Toy 123' with 1$ and 2$, 'Toy 456' with 2$ and 3$. In this case a composite key of name + price would make sense. A composite key of ID + name or ID + price on the other hand doesn't make sense, because the ID alone should already uniquely identify a record.

Comment: Maybe you want `PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE key (name)`. But then your table name doesn't make much sense, as you are not combining names with prices, but merely list names along with their attributes. (So `name` would then be a better table name, but well, much better would be something meaningful of course like `products` where name and price would be attributes, but the name would be unique.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply missing the varchar length for the name. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE name_price (
  id int NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  price int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
);
```